# Can't install parcel using [npm i --save-dev parcel]

Tags: npm, parcel

I'm trying to install parcel and used the command given in the official documentation

```
npm install --save-dev parcel
```

It outputs some warnings saying it's deprecated and errors as follows.

```
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\Courses\Front-End\Workspace\Trainings & Challenges\Jonas Schmedtman\17-Modern JS\node_modules\lmdb-store
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp-build
npm ERR! The system cannot find the path specified.
npm ERR! internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
npm ERR!   throw err;
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Courses\Front-End\Workspace\node-gyp-build\bin.js'
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
npm ERR!     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
npm ERR!   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
npm ERR!   requireStack: []
npm ERR! }

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Muhammad\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-22T14_51_13_204Z-debug-0.log
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Error Screenshot]

Eventually parcel isn't installed. any help please.
I'm using VS code on Win 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to install parcel again today with some patience and it worked.
It turned out that my address has a folder with an ampersand `&` in it that causes the problem even though that the folder name contains a space. Wierd thing that other packages was installed successfully without having any problem.

Old Address:

```
D:\Courses\Front-End\Workspace\Trainings & Challenges\Jonas Schmedtman\17-Modern JS
```

New Address:

```
D:\Courses\Front-End\Workspace\Trainings Challenges\Jonas Schmedtman\17-Modern JS
```

Answer (score 0):

If the verified answer didn't work for you:-
I uninstalled node and downloaded the latest version, allowing it to install other apps like python in the installation process and ran `npm i parcel --save-dev`
in visual studio's terminal and it worked with No Errors.